# Working with C++ without C

Tags: c++

Conceptually, my home language is Python. I did some C during the last semester and can understand the way it works, but I do not like raw pointers, raw mallocs and the lack of classes. I do like the speed and compiling though. C++ looks really good to me.

However, when I try to write some small programs in it and look specific tasks up, I often find C code again. I was going to send a simple GET request, and somebody suggested using cURL, which is a C library. Using that would break me out of my C++ abstraction again.

Is it possible to program in C++ without having to revert to C for most tasks? To me, C++ looks like a coherent language, but not like a stand-alone ecosystem.

Comment: You need to look better, there is e.g. Poco. Just wondering, is this question more than a rant?

Comment: If you like the speed of compiling C, C++ is going to be a disappointment! But seriously, C++ is a multi-paradigm language. If you want to get the fullest out of C++, you should be ready to do procedural, object-oriented, functional etc programming all at the same time.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier I do not intend this to be a rant about either C or C++. It is just that I would like to know where to look for C++ libraries that do not involve C.

Comment: @Shahbaz I do not like the speed of compiling the code itself, I like the speed that it later runs with. Compared to Python or Java.

Comment: Get to know [Boost](http://www.boost.org)!

Comment: It will be impossible to avoid C completely as for instance to interface with Windows through WinAPI you will have to use C functions. Also system functions ander linux are regular C functions.

Comment: @queueoverflow: A search engine? The results need to be filtered, but that's not specific to C++.

Comment: and Qt is a good framework.

Comment: Learn the standard library and boost.

Comment: You could try [boost](http://www.boost.org/). [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) is another nice C++ library with GUI support.

Comment: This is really more of a discussion rather than a question. C++ has a lot of history and a lot of different attitudes / practices around it. You are still right at the platform as well, so while it gives a lot of high-level features, you will still need to deal with things at the binary-level. For example passing data between modules gets tricky. Most popular libraries have C++ wrappers to access them. That's the same way you'd use curl in other languages.

Comment: [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/), and [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt), and especially [Boost](http://www.boost.org/).

Comment: The C++ is the super set o C and as such it CAN use C functions, however the problem is, what to do with the libraries written in pure C, there are some libraries that wrap them but not for all of the libraries that there are.

Comment: @cerkiewny Sorry but you are wrong. Although there are strong similarities, C and C++ are different languages. C++ IS NOT a superset of C (guess what type a simple character literal as `'a'` is in C and in C++).

Comment: Well all the standard C code can be used within C++ so it is the super set in my simple mind.

Comment: @MM. As far as I have seen it, Qt is more than just a toolkit, since it requires the whole Program to be a Qt program? Unlike Boost, where I can just pick some parts that I like?

Comment: @cerkiewny "...all the standard C code...", sorry but your assumptions are wrong. Just to expand the previous example: `'a'` has type `int` in C and type `char` in C++, and this is "standard" in both languages. It is a common misunderstanding, sure, but it is still wrong. The fact that you can find a common subset of features with identical syntax AND semantics doesn't make C a subset of C++.

Comment: @queueoverflow: Yes. Qt has big advantages also.

Comment: @cerkiewny As someone else has already pointed out, C++ designers wanted C++ code to interoperate with C, and this caused the misunderstanding (probably). The languages had some influence on each other's evolution, but still you cannot take an arbitrary conforming C program and compile it as C++ and still hope it will have the same semantics (assuming it compiles).

Comment: @cerkiewny Also, the following is valid (possibly idiomatic) C but invalid C++: `int* ptr = malloc(5 * sizeof(int));`. C++ does not implicitly convert void pointers like C does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

People often write libraries in C, in preference to C++, because of its greater interoperability. If you write a C++ library, you can only directly use it from C++. If you write a C library, you can use it from C++, C, Fortran, Python, C#, etc.

One of the major design considerations for C++ was that it interoperate with C, precisely because of the existence of this large body of libraries. The designers of C++, in other words, wanted you to be able to use C libraries. Act accordingly.

Comment: If you're talking about shared libraries (.dll/.so) to use codes in another languages.  What does stop you to export C++ codes to Fortran, Python, C# ?

Comment: The lack of a standardized ABI, basically. There's no convention for exactly how virtual function binding works, how exceptions are propagated, how names are mangled, etc.

Comment: You can always use extern "C"

Comment: In which case you're writing a C wrapper around your C++ library. Which is not a bad thing to do, though often a C-wrapped C++ interface becomes quite clunky (particularly when dynamic memory is involved), where it would not have, had it been C-targeted from the ground up. Ultimately, I think most authors of C++ libraries are simply not targeting interoperability, whereas authors of C don't have much work to do in order to get interoperability "for free".